# How to introduce automatic gain control over two mics using audio interface, DAW and a mixer

Tags: microphone, mixer, daw, audio-interfaces, automation

I'm having [Behringer UMC202HD](https://www.behringer.com/Categories/Behringer/Computer-Audio/Interfaces/UMC202HD/p/P0BJZ#googtrans(en%7Cen)) as an audio interface and [Studiomaster DC8.2](http://www.studiomasterprofessional.com/product/item/226) as a mixer.

I am looking to introduce [automixer](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Automixer) system using the above-mentioned hardware for the live production in an auditorium hall.

My use case is to use multiple microphones (2 for now), such that, when one in use, another's gain gets compressed, hence, lowering the chance of audio-loops (whistles) and vice versa.

I want to know if I can achieve the same with available hardware and if yes then how? and if no, then what can I do to achieve the same. I am completely new in managing audios.

I have been thinking following to achieve the required:

1. Plug Microphones into the audio interface,
2. Using any DAW to achieve automatic gain control over two mics, and returning the output from DAW to audio interface OUTs
3. Inserting Outputs of Audio interface as inputs to mixer,
4. Using mixer's master out as final out to speakers.

If the above flow works, then the major thing that I am worried about is DAW, I don't know which DAW can fulfill my requirement. If possible, please suggest any open-source one, else paid as well works.

If I am going completely wrong, please suggest a way out for a system where I can introduce automixer over multiple microphones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Dugan automixer. This can be acquired as either a hardware processing device, as software inside an existing hardware device such as a mixer, or as a VST plugin.

I strongly don't recommend you attempt to re-engineer the Dugan algorithm with discrete plugins - this will be re-inventing the wheel and will ultimately fail as standard compressors don't have the correct architecture for this to work correctly.

Waves sell a Dugan VST, but your best bet is to purchase a mixer that has this built in as this will also negate any latency issues that will inevitably arise when using an audio interface and VST.

Comment: Good to know, I was trying to reinvent the wheel, thanks for saving me. Can you recommend some good mixers for the same? I prefer analog mixers, but hybrids can work as well. I have a minimum requirement of 8 channels.

Comment: If you're looking at an analogue mixer you will need a hardware dugan. Best be looking at something like a Yamaha QL-series mixer. I believe that the CL-series also now has dugan integrated as part of the latest software update, but you will have to check to see if that is available in your region. QL is definite for dugan.

Comment: The Allen and Heath Qu-16 also has 16 channel automatic mic mixing and is much cheaper than a QL or CL. I have both the Qu-16 and QL5.

Comment: Is it Dugan or a different algorithm? Asking for a friend....

Comment: @Mark I believe it tries to mimic Dugan but it is not. I honestly haven’t used it so I don’t know how it compares to the Dugan one on Yamaha, which I have used and works well for Q&A panels. Haven’t used it for anything else.

Comment: Are there any more cheaper solutions?

Comment: Second hand hardware device probably. There is also automixing built into the Sound Device series of recorders - particularly 788T and you can probably pick up a second hand one of those as well. Also the 6xx series I believe.